# MongoDB geoNear returning blank when paginating

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, ecmascript-6, mongodb-query

Im trying to bring back a list of profiles. This worked fine used find()

But I needed to switch to aggregate for distance sorting.

Now instead of getting my full 100 record by 20 each. I get 40 and it's as if it doesnt find the rest.

Any help?
(yes I have tried with a simple geoNear filter. Same result)

```
 await Profile.aggregate([
      {
        $geoNear: {
          near: {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: [long, lat]
          },
          distanceMultiplier:
            req.user.distanceMetric === "km" ? 0.001 : 0.000621371, // meter to ki:miles
          distanceField: "distance",
          spherical: true,
          maxDistance: distance !== 100 ? distance * 1609.34 : 99999999999
        }
      },
      {
        $match: {
          $and: [
            {
              _id: {
                $ne: Profile.castID(req.user.profileID),
                $nin: doNotDisplayList.map(id => Profile.castID(id))
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      { $skip: skip },
      { $limit: limit }
    ]).sort({
      online: -1
    });
```

Comment: Can you share `skip` and `limit` values? Also, add `$sort` before skip / limit to get coherent result

Comment: @Valijon . skip starts at 0 and goes up every call.
limit is 20.
Wouldnt sort be last?

Comment: I see. Sort should be before skip / limit. Please share sample data

Comment: @Valijon. I've removed sort and same result. Im testing by getting the length of the array it creates.
I've narrowed it down to the geoNear cauing the issue. Without it I get results using match/skip/limit up to the entire results count.

When I use geo it stops at like 45 out of 117.

Comment: UPDATE: I tested using just match and geoNear. It seems geoNear is only returning 45 results while without it,118 is returned